# Fetching multiple objects at the same time in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

```
import { React, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css";

const FetchStocks = () => {
const API_KEY = "W2QUHNG3L8W8A5VN";
const [data, setData] = useState({ StockSymbols: null, StockName: null, StockIndustry: null })
const [MSFT, setMSFT] = useState({ MSFTSymbols: null, MSFTName: null, MSFTIndustry: null })
const [AA, setAA] = useState({ AASymbols: null, AAName: null, AAIndustry: null })

useEffect(() => {

    fetch(`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol=IBM&apikey=${API_KEY}`)
        .then(
            function (response) {
                return response.json();
            }
        )
        .then(
            function (data) {
                setData({
                    StockSymbols: data['Symbol'],
                    StockName: data['Name'],
                    StockIndustry: data['Industry']
                })
            })
}, [])

useEffect(() => {

    fetch(`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol=MSFT&apikey=${API_KEY}`)
        .then(
            function (response) {
                return response.json();
            }
        )
        .then(
            function (MSFT) {
                setMSFT({
                    MSFTSymbols: MSFT['Symbol'],
                    MSFTName: MSFT['Name'],
                    MSFTIndustry: MSFT['Industry']
                })
            })
}, [])

useEffect(() => {

    fetch(`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol=AA&apikey=${API_KEY}`)
        .then(
            function (response) {
                return response.json();
            }
        )
        .then(
            function (AA) {
                setAA({
                    AASymbols: AA['Symbol'],
                    AAName: AA['Name'],
                    AAIndustry: AA['Industry']
                })
            })
}, [])

const table = {
    columns: [
        { headerName: "Symbol", field: "symbol" },
        { headerName: "Name", field: "name" },
        { headerName: "Industry", field: "industry" }
    ],

    rowData: [
        { symbol: `${data.StockSymbols}`, name: `${data.StockName}`, industry: `${data.StockIndustry}` },
        { symbol: `${MSFT.MSFTSymbols}`, name: `${MSFT.MSFTName}`, industry: `${MSFT.MSFTIndustry}` },
        { symbol: `${AA.AASymbols}`, name: `${AA.AAName}`, industry: `${AA.AAIndustry}` }
    ],
}

let containerStyle = {
    height: 500,
    width: 700
}

return (
    <div>
        <div
            className="ag-theme-balham"
            style={containerStyle}
        >
            <AgGridReact
                columnDefs={table.columns}
                rowData={table.rowData}
                pagination={true}
            />
        </div>
    </div>
)
};

export default FetchStocks;
```

This is the code I have for creating a table showing stocks in it.

I'm using Alpha Vantage API for this and want to fetch multiple stocks to show in a table.

However, I'm havinig trouble because I'm using useEffect multiple times to get the elements of different stocks.

Is there any way that I can make it short?

For example I want to have symbol, name, industry of three stocks (IBM, MSFT, AA) to show up in a table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes... You can take the advantage of Promise.all() here.

```js
function getData() {
  let firstAPICall = fetch(`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol=IBM&apikey=${API_KEY}`);
  let secondAPICall = fetch(`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol=AA&apikey=${API_KEY}`);

  Promise.all([firstAPICall, secondAPICall])
    .then(values => Promise.all(values.map(value => value.json())))
    .then(finalVals => {
      let firstAPIResp = finalVals[0];
      let secondAPIResp = finalVals[1];
      renderHTML(firstAPIResp, secondAPIResp);
    });
}
```